# How to create a simple scheduler using gevent?

Tags: python, gevent

I was looking for a simple scheduler implementation using gevent. It seems `gevent.core.event` is able to do this but I am not sure.

The scheduler is very simple. I want to be able to schedule tasks to be executed later in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `gevent.spawn_later` which will take seconds, a callback function and the *args and **kwargs for the callback.

Here is the doc on that http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html#gevent.spawn_later